# Why SQL cast string '210' as number 21?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Использую MSSQL и обнаружил странное поведение.

При попытке преобразовать строку «210» в число, чтобы использовать ее в SUM. он преобразует его как число 21, а не 210, или суммирует его как число 21.

На самом деле я не могу определить, является ли это неправильным преобразованием или неправильным суммированием. Моя функция преобразования классическая:

```
try_cast('210' as NUMBER(18,2))
```

Я заметил, что «210.01» работает нормально! и 211 тоже работает как надо, даже 200 работает а 210 нет.

Comment: На русском stackoverflow нужно задавать вопросы на русском языке, переведите иначе вопрос закроют

Comment: select cast('210' as dec(18,2))

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: SQL Server должен был послать. Откуда ему знать, что такое NUMBER? Вот кабы INT или там DECIMAL...

Comment: У меня в SQL Server отработало корректно "SELECT SUM(CAST('210' AS NUMERIC(18,2)))". "NUMBER(18,2)" - это тип не из MS SQL, может у вас всё же другая СУБД? Такой запрос должен упасть на этапе парсинга, ещё до выполнения, с ошибкой: "Incorrect sintaksis"

Answer (score -1):

В MS SQL Server:

```
SELECT TRY_CAST('210' AS DECIMAL(18,2)) AS Result;
```

**Результат**

```
+--------+
| Result |
+--------+
| 210.00 |
+--------+
```

Comment: Есть ли причина понизить (downvote) ответ?